# Настройка заголовков при редиректе на haproxy

Tags: nginx, identityserver4

Нужна помощь, кто разбирается в nginx и haproxy.
Проблема: Я использую IdentityServer 4 и ASP.NET Identity как микросервис. Размещаю микросервис при помощи докера на сервере digital ocean.
Для настройки работы через https использовал haproxy.
В итоге получил проблему при переадресации. Возможное решение нашел только для варианта nginx([ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635169/configure-identityserver4-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy)):

```
location /api/ {
proxy_pass http://localhost:3110;

proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```

}

Мне вероятно надо сделать похожие настройки в haproxy. Вот что у меня там сейчас:

```
frontend www
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/letsencrypt/live/airvector.site/all.pem
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
    use_backend www
backend www
    server docker1 127.0.0.1:5000 check
```

Ну или похожие манипуляции с заголовками.

Answer (score 0):

Методом проб и ошибок, сам нашел решение, которое намного проще чем у nginx:

```
reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
```

Добавил эту строчку в frontend вкладку - теперь все работает: https://airvector.site/.well-known/openid-configuration